# Why i get this error when i try to make a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three classes:

```
class Valoration < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :points, presence:true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 100 }
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :hability
end
#################################################################
class Hability < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 16 }
    has_many :valorations
end
#################################################################
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: {strict: true}
    #validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
    validates :telephone, uniqueness: true, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, presence: true, length: { minimum: 9, maximum: 9 }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 30 }, format: { with: /^[\w\s-]*/u, multiline: true,
                                                                                    message: 'only allows letters' }
    has_many :valorations
  end
```

And here is the db scheme to left things clear

```
        ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150709141437) do

      create_table "habilities", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      end

      create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "password"
        t.integer  "telephone"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      end

      create_table "valorations", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.integer  "hability_id"
        t.integer  "points"
        t.string   "date"
        t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
      end

      add_index "valorations", ["hability_id"], name: "index_valorations_on_hability_id"
      add_index "valorations", ["user_id"], name: "index_valorations_on_user_id"

    end
```

Valorations is a resource in users:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :valorations
  end
```

In users/show.html.erb i have this link to:

```
<%= link_to 'View valorations on this user', user_valoration_path%>
<%= link_to 'Valorate user:',new_user_valoration_path(@user)%>
```

but when i load the page it gives me this error:

```
Showing /home/manuel/Documentos/ComoMeVeis/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #11 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"valorations", :id=>"2"} missing required keys: [:user_id]
```

I think there is something wrong with the table association because it says: valorations :id = 2, but then it says id = 2 
I'm new to rails and i dont know how to fix this, if you need more information about the code just comment it, any help is welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The following routes

```
resources :users do
  resources :valorations
end
```

generate

```
GET /users/:user_id/valorations/:id
GET /users/:user_id/valorations
```

and some other irrelevant to this answer

The issue is on this `link_to`

```
<%= link_to 'View valorations on this user', user_valoration_path%>
```

`user_valoration_path` will try to display one user valoration which means you need the `user` and the `valoration` to display.

I'm assuming from the text of the link that you want to display ALL valorations for the user so you'll need to use the following

`user_valorations_path(@user)`

That will direct to the path `/users/1/valorations` rather than `/users/1/valorations/...`

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, i have changed what you said and now  
NoMethodError in Valorations#index

Showing /home/manuel/Documentos/ComoMeVeis/app/views/valorations/index.html.erb where line #19 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass           
18
19
20
21
22
              

 

<% @valorations.each do |valoration| %>
<tr>
<td><%= valoration.user.name %></td>
<td><%= valoration.hability.name %></td>
<td><%= valoration.points %></td>
<td><%= valoration.date %></td>

Comment: That's a completely different issue from your original question/problem. I'd be happy to help you over chat or if you want create a new question. In any case, this answer solves your original issue.

Comment: A quick gist as to your follow up issue, it seems that you're calling `name` on an object that's nil. From what I can see in your code, either the `valoration.user` or the `valoration.hability` is nil. If you wrap those two calls in conditionals checking to make sure they are not nil your code should work...